# Can't set search as tableHeaderRow

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, swift, uisearchbar

Maybe this was already asked a million times & i really googled & tried to search stackoverflow but nothing seemed to help.

I have a tableview with custom cell class & above it a search bar & search Display controller. I'm trying to have my search bar move along with the table view. I added the following Swift code to

```
viewDidLoad:

searchBar.delegate = self;
myTable.tableHeaderView = searchBar;
```

But all it did is just remove the search bar & now when i scroll, my screen gets filled with a white cover above the table view.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Could someone please help ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: please post example code of your implementation

Comment: http://imgur.com/y0x16yd - This is a screenshot of my code, since I can't post the whole code here, says it's too long.

Comment: You could just copy the relevant bit of the code and post that...

Comment: donnywals, sorry, I'm new to Stackoverflow and not sure how this works here. I posted the piece of code I thought it was important in the original question, which got edited by Mayur (thank you for that).

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Somehow the searchBar outlet got disconnected creating this result. xCode didn't throw an error because from the coding point of view it looked correct, though I presume would be nice to have an alert when there is an unlinked @IBAction or @IBAlert in a swift file.